# defining {1} with just n+k=l in $\Bbb{N}$ and proving identity is the only automorphism in that kind of structures

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Let $\mathscr A$ be a structure $<N, s^{\mathscr A}>$ for the predicate language without formal equality $\mathscr L$, having a predicate symbol s with an arity of 3, where
$<n,k,l> \in s^\mathscr A \iff n+k=l$

Prove that:

1. Every of the sets {0}, {1}, {3}, {(n,k)|5 divides n-k} is definable in $\mathscr A$ with a formula from $\mathscr L$
2. the identity function is the only automorphism in $\mathscr A$

**My Solution:**

1.
$\phi_0(x) \equiv \forall y s(x,y,y)$

Since I couldn't define {1} with just summation of two natural numbers my approach is to define a formula which defines a natural number multiplied some number of times:

$$
\mu_0(x,y) \equiv \exists z(\phi_0(z) \& s(x,z,y)) \\
\mu_1(x,y) \equiv \exists z(\phi_0(z) \& s(x,z,y)) \\
\mu_2(x,y) \equiv s(x,x,y) \\
... \\
\mu_n(x, y) \equiv \exists z \mu_{n-1}(x,z) \& s(x,z,y)
$$

And from there using $\mu_n$ I define the singleton set {1}
$$
\phi_1(x) \equiv \forall y \mu_y(x,y)
$$

**Edit**

The actual way to define {1} is by first defining the relation $\le$ and then using it. The previous way is not correct since n is a subscript and not a free variable.
$$
\phi_{\le}(x, y) \equiv \exists k \ \ s(x,k,y) \\
\phi_1(x) \equiv \forall y \ \ \neg \phi_0(y) \implies phi_{\le}(x,y)
$$

And having a formula for {1} I define the rest of the singleton sets in the following manner:

$$
\phi_2(x) \equiv \exists y \phi_1(y) \& s(y,y,x) \\
\phi_3(x) \equiv \exists y \exists z (\phi_2(y) \& \phi_1(z) \& s(y,z,x)) \\
\phi_5(x) \equiv \exists y \exists z (\phi_3(y) \& \phi_2(z) \& s(y,z,x)) \\
\phi_{strange}(n,k) \equiv \exists x \exists y \exists z(\phi_5(z) \& s(x,k,n) \& \mu_y(x,z))  \\
$$

For proving 2. I have a vague idea which I'm not sure is correct.
First I prove inductively that every element is definable in the given structure.

- {0} - we already defined that using the formula $\phi_0$
- (Inductive Step) Assuming we have defined $\phi_n$ we can define $\phi_{n+1}$ like this
  $\phi_{n+1}(x) \equiv \exists y \exists z(\phi_n(y) \& \phi_1(z) \& s(y,z,x))$

From that we see that every element is definable in the structure $\mathscr A$

We know that if there's an automorphism h(a) s.t. $h(a) \neq a$, the element a is not definable in the structure. Then if we assume there's another automorphism different from the identity and pick any element we see that it's not definable, which leads to contradiction with the fact that we have defined every element in the structure.

**My questions are:**

- Is my solution so far correct, formal and rigorous enough?
- Is the definition for the multiplication formula correct and formal in the way I've defined it? I'm not sure I can define a formula in the given manner.
- Is my idea (sort of proof) for 2. correct, and if not how should I prove it?

Comment: $\mu_n$ is a formula depending on $n$, but $n$ isn't a free variable of this formula so you can't define the formula $\forall y, \mu_y$. Your idea for 2. is correct, if indeed every element is definable (and if you manage to prove that $1$ is indeed definable, then every element will be, by induction). To define 1, try to write the following sentence "every element but $0$ is greater than $1$", and notice that in $\Bbb{N}$, $n\leq m\iff \exists k, n+k=m$

Comment: @Max Thank you! How can I define {1} then?

Comment: I've edited my comment to give you a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how your $\mu_n$ function is supposed to work ...

Here is one way to define a predicate $\phi_1(x)$ that under the given interpretation wil only be true for $x=1$:

$$\phi_1(x) \equiv \forall y \forall z (s(y,x,z) \land \neg \phi_0(x) \land \neg \exists u \exists v \exists w (\neg \phi_0(u) \land \neg \phi_0(v) \land s(y,u,w) \land s(w,v,x)))$$

Comment: Yes, it can't work like that. What I did, after reading @Max comment, was 
$\phi_{\le}(x,y) \equiv \exists k \ \ s(x,k,y) $ and then with it I defined {1} - $\phi_1(x) \equiv \forall y \ \ \neg \phi_0(y) \land \phi_{\le}(x,y)$ What do you think about the rest of the problem, assuming {1} is defined correctly?

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov : it should be an $\implies$, not an $\land$. What you've written is a formula that is false in your model: as it stands, $\forall x, (\phi_1(x)\implies \neg \exists y, \phi_0(y))$